# typeahead.js: Return all Bloodhound records on empty query

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

i use bloodhound to get some data for typeahead. My Bloodhound Object:

```
var lastAdresses = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: {
    url: '/_dev_data_sources/last_adresses_json.html',
  },
  limit: 20
});



lastAdresses.initialize().done(function () {
  var query = "L";
  lastAdresses.get(query, function(suggestions) {
  console.log(suggestions);
  });
});
```

This works fine, when my query is "L" like in the example, or another string. But I want bloodhound to return all available Records, when my query is "". In my example, it returns nothing.

I saw, that bloodhound has a filter argument, but I don`t know how to use this.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You want typeahead to display all suggestions as soon as the page loads?

Comment: Yes, this was my intention. I saw that the typeahead-team is working on it but I can`t wait. And it works now by adding a observer function as source which checks if the query is "" and if it is so it returns all data as array.

Comment: Can u post the code somewhere to show this? I am also need to show all records... Thanks =)

Comment: I would find this useful as well. Any solutions?

Comment: I found an answer to a similar question. Try this link.

[Show full list of suggestions on click with typeahead and bloodhound][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27145346/4799064

Answer (score 13):

I think there might be a better way of doing this. But it still depends on internal bloodhound implementation that may change.

```
var searchEngine = new Bloodhound({...});
function searchWithDefaults(q, sync) {
  if (q === '') {
    sync(searchEngine.index.all());
  } else {
    searchEngine.search(q, sync);
  }
}
$("#typeahead").typeahead({
  minLength : 0,
}, {
  name : 'typeahead',
  source : searchWithDefaults
});
```

This code takes advantage of implementation of Bloodbound internal search engine called [`SearchIndex`](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/src/bloodhound/search_index.js) and its function `all()` that returns full list of data stored by Bloodhound.

Answer inspired by:

- [Twitters Typeahed example with default suggestions](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#default-suggestions)
- joews answer

Answer (score 1):

Bloodhound uses an internal type called [`SearchIndex`](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/src/bloodhound/search_index.js) for efficient matching of query terms.

You can [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) `SearchIndex.get` to change the records that are returned for a given query.

This function patches a Bloodhound instance to return all records for an empty query term:

```
// Patch the given Bloodhound instance
//  to match all records for an empty query
function enableMatchAll(bloodhound) {
  var _get = bloodhound.index.get;
  bloodhound.index.get = function(query) {
    if(!query || query === '') {
      return this.datums;
    } else {
      return _get.call(this, query);
    }
  }
}
```

[JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/tupaqo/4/edit)

Be aware that this patch uses undocumented internal functionality. It works for typeahead/bloodhound v0.10.5; it may or may not work with any other version.