# Cannot post Id with Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I use Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead in my MVC5 project and it list the related records properly. Although I can retrieve the Id value of the selected record on updater section, I cannot post it on form submit. I tried many different combinations of the Id parameter, but did not make any sense. How to post Id parameter with Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead?

**View:**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StudentId)

<input id="StudentId" name="StudentId" type="text" class="form-control tt-input" 
    autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto">

<script>
    $("#StudentId").typeahead({
        minLength: 1,
        source: function (query, process) {
            var lookups = [];
            map = {};

            // This is going to make an HTTP post request to the controller
            return $.post('/Grade/StudentLookup?query=%QUERY', { query: query }, function (data) {

                // Loop through and push to the array
                $.each(data, function (i, lookup) {
                    map[lookup.Name] = lookup;
                    lookups.push(lookup.Name);
                });

                // Process the details
                process(lookups);
            });
        },
        updater: function (item) {
            var selectedId = map[item].Id;
            console.log("Selected : " + selectedId);
            return item;
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult StudentLookup(string query)
{
    var students = repository.Students.Select(m => new StudentViewModel
    {
        Id = m.Id,
        Name = m.Name + " " + m.Surname                
    })
    .Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith(query));
    return Json(students, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: what does the console error say, and can you console.log map and item in the updater function and lookups in the source function ? I think your problem is `map` is not global tho.

Comment: I get the Id parameter as "selectedId" on selectedIndexChange but cannot assign it to the StudentId model value. So, the only problem is this and could you please clarify me about how can I assign it to Model.StudentId?

Comment: ah, I would recommend you use a hidden field / another field and assign the ID to it, else you confuse the user why a number was placed where he expected a name.

Comment: Yes, I also tried to use hidden field ans try to set this value by **$('#StudentId').value = selectedId ;** in update section. But did not work and posted StudentId value is 0 while the console.log() has the StudentId value properly. Any answer pls?

Comment: you can try .val(selectedId) like in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seperate the fields into Name and Id, you can even make the ID field hidden or readonly.

```
<input id="StudentName" type="text" class="form-control tt-input" 
    autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto">

<input id="StudentId" name="StudentId" type="text">

<script>
    $("#StudentName").typeahead({
        minLength: 1,
        source: function (query, process) {
            var lookups = [];
            map = {};

            // This is going to make an HTTP post request to the controller
            return $.post('/Grade/StudentLookup?query=%QUERY', { query: query }, function (data) {

                // Loop through and push to the array
                $.each(data, function (i, lookup) {
                    map[lookup.Name] = lookup;
                    lookups.push(lookup.Name);
                });

                // Process the details
                process(lookups);
            });
        },
        updater: function (item) {
            var selectedId = map[item].Id;
            console.log("Selected : " + selectedId);
            $("#StudentId").val(selectedId)
            return item;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. I just made I mistake for assigning hidden value with $('#StudentId').value = selectedId; instead of **$("#StudentId").val(selectedId);** :) Thanks a lot.. On the other hand, is there a smarter feature of typeahead for posting ID value?

Comment: Calm down, I need a minute to answer :P No, this is the way to do it. I usualy use Bloodhound https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#bloodhound for a nicer layout tho.

Comment: Sorry :) Could you please clarify me about the advantages of Bloodhound to Typeahead? Is it only layout? For ASP.NET MVC, which one do you suggest?

Comment: Well look at the link. You get more control over the suggestions, local storage, etc - but at the end you still have to post the ID like anywhere else.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and useful explanations.

Comment: I decided to switch to Bloodhound :) But I am not sure if I can use it as Combobox + Autocomplete? I mean that if the user have no idea about the list he cen also list all the records by using the control as combobox or dropdownlist also. ıs there any example for it? At the page you suggested, there are manual suggestions instead of listing all records. Any help please?

Comment: bloodhound is not the right tool in this case, but there are some ways you can force it into showing all results, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429918/typeahead-js-return-all-bloodhound-records-on-empty-query

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I tried to apply it, but it seems to be not suitable example for loading remote data in ASP.NET MVC. Is there any good example of Bloodhound for ASP.NET MVC? On the other hand, what about Bootstrap Select2 droddown vs Bloodhound? I just want autocomplete feature, listing all records and preventing from entering data except from the list. Any idea?