# Typeahead.js: don't show all options when clicking

Tags: typeahead.js

This is the opposite of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797370/twitter-typeahead-js-show-all-options-when-click-focus) or [this issue](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/798). Currently, typeahead.js (0.11.1) shows the options available after clicking on its input field.

I'm not sure I want that behavior and I'd like to know if there is an [option](https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#options) to change/disable it.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? There is not an option to disable it. There are options that affect behavior.

Comment: Probably is mostly a personal preference. I usually want to provide suggestions after typing, not so much after focusing on the input field. In your experience, why do people want to show options after clicking on the input field?

Comment: That only happens if: 1) there is something in the text box already 2) you've added defaults

Comment: Yes, I understand that's the current behavior. In my case, this occurs after adding text to the box. You might want to add your comment as a response.